# How to use this CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(function) by manually?

Tags: iphone

I am working on get listing of directories from the ftp server in whivh I am using CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing function. But I want to use this functions functionality with out using this function. Is it possible? If yes then please give me advice.

Comment: What's wrong with this function?

Comment: After using this function we cant encoding string.So i want to use manually.